# How to drop DataFrame columns based on dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a pandas dataframe and I'm trying to drop all the object fields from so that I'm left with only numeric.

I've been trying to write a for loop to do this task, as I'm likely going to need to do it over and over again with different data.

For some reason I can't get it working. Below is what I've did so far

```
for cols in data:
    if data.values.type == object:
        numdata = data.drop(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The error I get is:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 for cols in data:
>   ----> 2     if data.values.type == object:
>         3         numdata = data.drop(axis=1, inplace=True)
>
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'type'

I am a newb and for some reason I can't get the for loop and if statement logic to stick in my head.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to exclude columns of a particular type.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'y': [1, 2, 3], 'z': ['d', 'e', 'f']})

df = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
print(df)
```

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks! I hadn't come across .select_dtypes before.

Comment: If you're trying to drop columns for a given dtype, use `df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])` instead of calling drop() as a second step.

Comment: A useful note from `select_dtypes` documentation about `'object'`: "To select strings you must use the object dtype, but note that this will return all object dtype columns". The post here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html