# How to drop DataFrame columns with dtype ndarray and dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray, dtype

As it says in the title, I have a pandas DataFrame with different data types (strings, floats, integers, ndarrays, dataframes, ect). I would like to drop all those columns with types ndarrays and dataframe (object dtype in pandas nomenclature), but I can't find a proper way.

I found in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) that 'To select strings you must use the object dtype, but note that this will return all object dtype columns'. And this is exactly my problem. I want to exclude the columns which values are ndarrays, but not those which are strings or e.g. pathlib.Path's.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817592/how-to-drop-dataframe-columns-based-on-dtype), where they just want to keep the numerical dtype columns, but again this is not exactly what I want and I can't find a way to properly do it.

I've tried

```
    dfSimple = df.select_dtypes (exclude=[np.ndarray])
```

but that leaves me with only `np.number` and `bool` types, exluding all others.

Comment: `df.dtypes` will give you all the columns and what their dtypes are. you could also do `df['col_name'].dtype` will give you the columns dtype

Comment: yes, I know that, but that doesn't help, since pandas considers np.ndarray, path.Pathlib, dataframe, string types as `object`. The thing is I just want to exclude those which are either np.ndarray or dataframe, and keep all the others.